# Create a DHCP working lab in HyperV (2012) all Internal

Tags: networking, dhcp, hyper-v-server-2012

I need to create a lab for testing purposes.

I got a good desktop on which i have installed a server 2012.

In HypverV, i have installed two 2012, one XP and one W8.

The idea is that the one and then two server 2012 distributes dhcp adresses to the deskops.

The issue is that even if the scope is activated in DHCP, the desktop only get a APIPA address. I can work with fixed ipadresses but that is not the purpose of the exercise.

That is how it has been setup.

Vm 2012 10.10.10.1/24
Vm 2012 V2 10.10.2/24

Roles installed ADDS,DNS,DHCP
DHCP scope 10.10.10/24 is activated

What am i missing to make the 2012 distributing ipadresses ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What kind of virtual switch did you create? Do all of the VM's have a virtual NIC connected to the same virtual switch?

Comment: The DHCP server is authorized? DHCP guard (http://windowsitpro.com/hyper-v/windows-server-2012-hyper-v-introduces-dhcp-guard) (in HyperV) disabled?